# Text Search in MongodDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nlp, keyword-search

Consider the following piece of code:

```
Transactions: [
               {name: 123, content: "Starbucks Coffee"},
               {name: 456, content: "Peets Coffee"},
               {name: 789, content: "Amazon gift card"},
               {name: 646, content: "amazon gift card"},
               {name: 779, content: "Acme Corp deposit cheque"},
               {name: 606, content: "acme corp deposit cheque"},
               {name: 879, content: "Dunkin-Donuts"},
               {name: 656, content: "Dunkin Donuts"}
              ];
```

I need to write a MongoDB framework which does the following:

case 1.)

Input: "Acme Corp" or "acme Corp" or "Acme corp" or "acme corp"

Expected Output:

```
       [
        {name: 779, content: "Acme Corp deposit cheque"},
        {name: 606, content: "acme corp deposit cheque"}
       ]
```

case 2.)

Input: "Amazon" or "amazon"

Expected Output:

```
       [
        {name: 789, content: "Amazon gift card"},
        {name: 646, content: "amazon gift card"}
       ]
```

case 3.)

Input: "Dunkin" or "dunkin" or "Dunkin-Donuts" or "dunkin-donuts" or "dunkin-Donuts" or "Dunkin-donuts" or "donuts" or "Donuts"

Expected Output:

```
       [
        {name: 879, content: "Dunkin-Donuts"},
        {name: 656, content: "Dunkin Donuts"}
       ]
```

Thank you! Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Your question title in a Google search [https://www.google.com/search?q=Text+Search+in+MongodDB](https://www.google.com/search?q=Text+Search+in+MongodDB) returns every relevant link you should have read before posting.

Answer (score 0):

### `$regex`

You can use `$regex` with the `i` flag for case-insensitivity:

```
transactions.find( { content: { $regex: /acme/i } } )
```

### `$text`

Or use `$text` (for better performance), by first creating a `text` index on the field(s) containing the text to be searched

```
transactions.createIndex( { content: "text" } )
```

and then:

```
transactions.find( { $text: { $search: "acme" } } )
```